# Rails active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

How would i do a query like this.
i have

```
@model = Model.near([latitude, longitude], 6.8)
```

Now i want to filter another model, which is associated with the one above.
 (help me with getting the right way to do this)

```
model2 = Model2.where("model_id == :one_of_the_models_filtered_above", {:one_of_the_models_filtered_above => only_from_the_models_filtered_above})
```

the model.rb would be like this

```
has_many :model2s
```

the model2.rb

```
belongs_to :model
```

Right now it is like this (after @model = Model.near([latitude, longitude], 6.8)

```
model2s =[]
models.each do |model|
   model.model2s.each do |model2|
      model2.push(model2)
   end
end
```

I want to accomplish the same thing,  but with an active record query instead

i think i found something, why does this fail

```
Model2.where("model.distance_from([:latitude,:longitude]) < :dist", {:latitude => latitude, :longitude => longitude, :dist => 6.8})
```

this query throws this error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "(": syntax error: SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags"  WHERE (model.distance_from([43.45101666666667,-80.49773333333333]) < 6.8)
```

, why

Comment: for the initial bit, can you use "IN" clause ? so like `Model2.where("model_id in ?", @models)`. In second part, are you trying to pass an array to distance_from? Can you have an attribute in model containing the value that could be used in the query instead of invoking distance_from method?

Comment: You'll have to implement your `distance_from` in SQLite's flavor of SQL or add a user-defined function to implement it.

Comment: You could use a `join` to select all Model2 objects that have a match in the query on Model

Answer (score 0):

use `includes`. It will eager-load associated models (only two SQL queries instead of N+1).

```
@models = Model.near( [latitude, longitude], 6.8 ).includes( :model2s )
```

so when you will do `@models.first.model2s`, associated model2s will already be loaded (see [RoR guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) for more info).

If you want to get an array of all model2s belonging to your collection of models, you can do :

```
@models.collect( &:model2s ) 
# add .flatten at the end of the chain if you want a one level deep array
# add .uniq at the end of the chain if you don't want duplicates
```

`collect` (also called `map`) will gather in an array the result of any block passed to each of the caller's elements (this does exactly the same as your code, see [Enumerable's doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) for more info). The `&` before the symbol converts it into a `Proc` passed to each element of the collection, so this is the same as writing

```
@models.collect {|model| model.model2s }
```

one more thing : @mu is right, seems SQLite does not know about your `distance_from` stored procedure. As i suspect this is a GIS related question, you may ask about this particular issue on [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)